# How to invalidate apollo android cache?

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-android

Here is my apollo client code for caching

```
val apolloSqlHelper = ApolloSqlHelper.create(context,"my_app")
        val sqlNormalizedCacheFactory = SqlNormalizedCacheFactory(apolloSqlHelper)
        val cacheKeyResolver = object: CacheKeyResolver(){
            override fun fromFieldRecordSet(
                field: ResponseField,
                recordSet: MutableMap<String, Any>
            ): CacheKey {
                return if (recordSet["__typename"] == "Repository") {
                    CacheKey.from(recordSet["id"] as String)
                } else {
                    CacheKey.NO_KEY
                }
            }

            override fun fromFieldArguments(
                field: ResponseField,
                variables: Operation.Variables
            ): CacheKey {
                return  CacheKey.NO_KEY
            }
        }

        ApolloClient.builder().serverUrl(baseUrl)
            .normalizedCache(sqlNormalizedCacheFactory,cacheKeyResolver)
            .okHttpClient(okHttpClient).build()
```

I am doing a query after which apollo caches my results but when more data is added to the query I am not understand how to invalidate the cache depending on whether results have changed or not. If no results changed get data from cache or fetch new data and update the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't need to manually invalidate the cache. Apollo Android handles it for me

This code worked for me

```
apolloClient.query(MyQuery()).responseFetcher(ApolloResponseFetchers.NETWORK_FIRST)
```

`ApolloResponseFetchers` also provide various options like `CACHE_FIRST`,`CACHE_ONLY` etc

Answer (score 0):

First option is using a specific `ResponseFetcher` on your query to adjust your cache strategy:

```kotlin
val query = someQuery.toBuilder()
    .responseFetcher(ApolloResponseFetchers.NETWORK_ONLY)
    .build()

apolloClient.query(query)
```

However if you need to invalidate cache for some specific cache key you may go ahead and use [ApolloStore](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/caching/store/).

```kotlin
apolloClient.apolloStore.remove(yourCacheKey)
```